# PHP is not supporting dll files of Biometrics Attendence Machine's SDK

Tags: php, dll

I have ZK Teco Bio-metrics Attendance Machine. I need to integrate this machine with my PHP project so our team can access this machine remotely to get their attendance record. Also, I have provided [Official SDK](http://www.zkteco.eu/index.php/downloads/software-downloads) that contains dll files.

I have copied the dll files in the path "C:\xampp\php\ext\" and included extensions to these files in "php.ini" file. But PHP doesn't support these dll files.

What should I do to use these dll files in my PHP project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZK Teco does not provide sdk for PHP. It only provides in C# and VB.net. So only dll files is not sufficient to do any thing until it supports that language. Because they don't provide sdk in php you don't have any option to integrate with php. You need to look from another provide or work in the given language. They have proper documentation for both C# and VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sql we can get the attendance details from biometric machine and we can use the the biometric data in php also.

Comment: how to use sql? @ madhu priya

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you need to create c# class and get the parameters while the parameters may be provided using PHP as API JSON.